# Break and Restart Calculation When Conditions meet in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, haversine

I have data that contains latitude and longitude. I want to eliminate data that abnormal. The detection based on speed and distance between data.

This is my sample data:

| No | Longitude | Latitude | Datetime | Distance | Speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 | 45.2 | 01-01-2021 | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 1.2 | 44.9 | 01-01-2021 | 10 | NaN |
| 3 | 1.2 | 45.1 | 01-01-2021 | 8 | 2 |
| 4 | 1.1 | 49.2 | 01-01-2021 | 100 | 50 |
| 5 | 1.1 | 49.2 | 01-01-2021 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 1.1 | 49.2 | 01-01-2021 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 1.4 | 45.3 | 01-01-2021 | 100 | 50 |

I use haversine calculation and speed to detect anomalies (speed above 20). The problem is my script only detect first anomaly (row 4) which actually the anomaly is the row 4 until 6. It can't detect the anomaly because the calculation based on previous row.

How to drop the first row of anomaly and then restart the script to calculate again so the row 5 and 6 can be detected as anomaly? Or there is any other ways to do that?

Sample code

```
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, to_radians=True, earth_radius=6371):
    if to_radians:
        lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2 = np.radians([lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])

    a = np.sin((lat2-lat1)/2.0)**2 + \
        np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin((lon2-lon1)/2.0)**2

    return earth_radius * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))

df['Distance'] = \
    np.concatenate(df.groupby('ID')
                     .apply(lambda x: haversine(x['Latitude'], x['Longitude'],
                                                x['Latitude'].shift(), x['Longitude'].shift())).values)

df['Time_Diff'] = df.sort_values(['ID','Datetime']).groupby('ID')['Datetime'].diff()

df['Time_Diff'] = df['Time_Diff'].dt.total_seconds()
df['Time_Diff'] = df['Time_Diff'] / 3600
df['Speed'] = df['Distance'] / df['Time_Diff']

df= df[df.Speed <= 20]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please share a code sample.

Comment: We also need a minimal data to reproduce. Here the `Datetime` column is constant, so we cannot compute any speed.